# How can I use $value$plusargs?

Tags: verilog

I'd like to use `$value$plusargs` as in the below code:

```
module top();
...
reg data;
real READ_FREQ

initial begin
if (!$value$plusargs("READ_FREQ=%0F", READ_FREQ))
 READ_FREQ = 197;
end

parameter wclk = 300;
parameter rclk = READ_FREQ;

always #(rclk/2.0) i_rclk = ~i_rclk;

...
endmodule
```

But, when I compile the code, I get this error:

```
irun: *E,VLGERR: An error occurred during parsing.  Review the log file for errors with the code *E and fix those identified problems to proceed.  Exiting with code (status 1).

irun(64): 12.10-p001: (c) Copyright 1995-2012 Cadence Design Systems, Inc.
file: ./top.v
parameter       rclk      = READ_FREQ;
                                         |
ncvlog: *E,NOTPAR (./top.v,197|41): Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
```

How can I use `$value$plusargs`?

Comment: The `$value$plusarg` is not the cause of your error. Parameters can only take constant expressions, i.e. operation on constant values or other parameters.   
You passed a real `READ_FREQ` which is a variable and causes this error.  

However, you can check http://www.project-veripage.com/plusarg.php for `$value$plusarg` usage

Comment: Your simulator should support `$value$plusargs`; it was added in IEEE1364-2001 so all simulators from 2005 and onward should support it. Check the lines above. `real READ_FREQ` is missing a `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign a run-time variable to a parameter. Parameters can only be assigned during compile (default values) and elaboration (override values). `$value$plusargs` is executed at run-time, it also cannot assign a parameter.

You haven't demonstrated where you need to use `rclk` other than the period value of `i_rclk`. You could modify your code to the following to get a the intended effect.

```
real READ_FREQ;

initial begin
  if (!$value$plusargs("READ_FREQ=%0F", READ_FREQ)) begin
    READ_FREQ = 197;
  end
  forever #(READ_FREQ/2.0) i_rclk = ~i_rclk;
end
```